# File in Base64 string occupies more space than original file

Tags: string

I'm in this kind of... Problem... I'm adding to my program the resources by encoding in base64 string the files (images, videos and audio) and adding them to a String. What I do is to read the file and then, convert the bytes to a Base64 string and write it to a txt file, but the txt file occupies slightly MORE space than the original file. Also this happens when I add the string to my program code. The compiled executable occupies a lot of space. Ex:

An MP3 file occupies 2.3 MB
The Base64 string in a txt file occupies 3.19 MB

Any solution or way to optimize the space of base64 string?

P.D. This is just something I'm trying to do for fun. Do not comment below "WHY" or the reason "FOR WHAT" I want this. The answer is: just for fun.

Comment: Base64 by definition will take up somewhat more space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's inherent to Base64.

Base64 uses 4 octets to encode 3 octets, because it's a reasonably efficient way of encoding arbitrary binary data using just those bytes that mean something printable in ASCII and also avoid many characters that are special in many contexts. It's more compact than say hexadecimal strings (2 octets to encode each octet), but always larger than raw binary. It's value is only in contexts where raw binary won't work, so the extra size is worth it.

(Strictly it's 4 characters to encode 3 octets, so if that was then encoded in UTF-16 or UTF-32 it could be 8 or 16 octets per 3 encoded).

Comment: Excelent! I totally forgot the encoding method and didn't knew it was due to Encoding format and UTF-16 or 32 would be larger D: Thanks! :))